# Black screen, can't log on

Tags: boot

I downloaded and installed the latest version of Ubuntu the other day. I rebooted after the install. Got the four dots okay but then instead of getting the logon screen, the screen went black. I have to restart the computer. I can run:
Advanced options
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-Generic (Recovery Mode)
or
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-19-Generic

Answer (score 0):

My Computer used to do the same thing, but i fixed it. Using the original disc (DVD) of the Operating system you are using, u can reinstall ubuntu while keeping all of your files safe.

If that doesnt work, you can update using the disc as well. This usually solves these problems too.